# Instagram auth leading to blank Web View in iOS9

Tags: ios, afnetworking, instagram

I had an auth routine that worked perfectly in iOS8 and now in iOS9, I'm having trouble with the exact same code.

I'm loading a webview with:
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code

```
let url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code"
        let wvc = WebViewController()
        wvc.title = "Add an Account"
        wvc.url = url
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: wvc)
        target.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the webview, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Cancel, target: self, action: "cancel")
    }
```

I'm just seeing a blank web view, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Add the following to `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a big trouble to answer: what are you using as MY_REDIRECT_URI?

I am trying http://localhost with no success on iOS - but works fine in browser.